# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY for JSON parsing using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY for JSON parsing using GSON.
I'm getting error which is occur due to class define for Gson Json implementation
Json Format which need to parse using GSON

```
{
    "StatusCode": 4,
    "Data": {            
        "Data": [
                 [
                   {"Value": "19"},{"Value": "19"}],
                 [               
                   {"Value": "77"},{"Value": "4"}
                 ]
                ],

        "ColumnHeaders": [
            {
                "Width": "11.0%",
                "Title": "Date"
            },
            {
                "Width": "7.6%",
                "Title": "Total Clicks"
            }
        ],
        "ColumnHeaderGroups": [
            {
                "ColSpan": "1",
                "Title": ""
            },
            {
                "ColSpan": "7",
                "Title": "Chats"
            },
            {
                "ColSpan": "3",
                "Title": "Times (HH:MM:SS)"
            }
        ],

        "ReportHeaders": [
            {
                "Name": "Title",
                "Value": "Chat Summary By Date"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Run Date",
                "Value": "05/03/2016 10:52:39 AM"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Time Zone",
                "Value": "GMT+00:00"
            }
        ],
        "Summary": [              
            {
                "Value": "96"
            },
            {
                "Value": "23"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Status": "success"
}
```

Classes for parsing using gson :

```
static class Page {
        String Status;
        Data Data;
    }

    static class Data {
        String ReportID;
    }

    static class Page1 {
        String StatusCode;
        String Status;
        Data1 Data;
    }

    static class Data1 {

        List <Data2> Data;
        List<ColumnHeaders> ColumnHeaders;
        List<ReportHeaders> ReportHeaders;
        List<Summary> Summary;
    }

    static class Data2{
        List<object1> object1;
    }
    static class object1 {
        String  Value;
    }

    static class ColumnHeaders {
        String Title;
    }

    static class Summary {
        String  Value;
    }

    static class ReportHeaders {
        String  Value;
    }
```

Code for parsing json using gson: 
need to parse

> "Value": "19","Value": "19","Value": "77","Value": "4"

inside Data Array[].

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
        Page1 page = gson.fromJson(json, Page1.class);
        String statusString = page.Status;
        System.out.println("Status : " + statusString);
        System.out.println("StatusCode : " + page.StatusCode);
        if ("success".equals(statusString)) {
            System.out.println("Inside if");
            for (ColumnHeaders item : page.Data.ColumnHeaders)
                System.out.print(item.Title + "     :");
            System.out.println();
            for (Summary item1 : page.Data.Summary)
                System.out.print(item1.Value + "    :");    
        }
```

Comment: The JSON for `Data1.Data` is array of array of object, so it should be `List<List<object1>>`, not `List<Data2>`. A clue would be that your `Data2` is an object with a field named `object1`, but your JSON doesn't have any objects with a field named that.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing pojo to this

```
class Data{
    @SerializedName("Data")
    @Expose
    private List<List<Data2>> Data = new ArrayList<List<Data2>>();
    @SerializedName("ColumnHeaders")
    @Expose
    private List<ColumnHeader> ColumnHeaders = new ArrayList<ColumnHeader>();
    @SerializedName("ReportHeaders")
    @Expose
    private List<ReportHeader> ReportHeaders = new ArrayList<ReportHeader>();
    @SerializedName("Summary")
    @Expose
    private List<Summary> Summary = new ArrayList<Summary>();
    //getter setter
}

class Data2{
   @SerializedName("Value")
   @Expose
   private String Value;
   //getter setter
}
```